# Store a Query in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012

How do I store a Query in SQL Server 2012 that can be inserted based on a key word?

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where COLUMN_NAME like '%%' order by TABLE_NAME
```

This Query Has to be inserted in  query window when i type **csearch** and press **ctrl+Space**  or **tab** replacing **csearch**

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @Cataklysim can you be more specific? I unable to find What i am looking for in the link you provided

Answer (score 0):

You can create SQL functions and stored procedures in your database. These functions can be called when needed.

```
CREATE FUNCTION CSEARCH
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    <@Param1, sysname, @p1> <Data_Type_For_Param1, , int>
)
RETURNS <Function_Data_Type, ,int>
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE <@ResultVar, sysname, @Result> <Function_Data_Type, ,int>

    -- Add the T-SQL statements to compute the return value here
    SELECT <@ResultVar, sysname, @Result> = <@Param1, sysname, @p1>

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN <@ResultVar, sysname, @Result>

END
GO
```

In this case, replace the `SELECT`with your query and run this script.
It will be saved in your database and can be altered by replacing `CREATE FUNCTION`with  `ALTER FUNCTION`.

To call this function, create a simple SQL Connection in your Code and select it like this:

`SELECT CSEARCH(param1, param2, ...) AS Function`

The returned value will be that one you declared inside your function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,but i don't want to call a function i need something like code  snippets in SQL server.I know the Features is Available,But i don't know how to achieve it!

Comment: Oh! I made it myself quiet hard. Sorry, misread it. Try `STRG` + `K` and `STRG` + `B` to open the snippet Manager or look in the "Extras" Tab @Sree

Comment: For Code Snippets we have to right click and select insert snippets or use Ctrl + k,Ctrl+ x and the have to select snippets. i need something much more faster

Comment: Usually you can give your Snippets shortcuts to find them faster in their Folder. If you dont use SSMS 2016, try ApexSQL Complete.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a procedure , and then assign it to a hotkey at SSMS.

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM sys.objects WHERE name = 'sp_SelectAllTablesLike')

DROP PROCEDURE sp_SelectAllTablesLike

GO

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_SelectAllTablesLike

@TableName VARCHAR(256)

AS

BEGIN

SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where COLUMN_NAME like '%' + @TableName + '%' ORDER BY TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME

END

GO
```

[image: Add the procedure to the SSMS hotkeys]

(here a longer explanation regarding how to add a procedure to SSMS hotkeys https://www.sqlshack.com/custom-keyboard-shortcuts-in-sql-server-management-studio-ssms/)

Restart SSMS.

Then, every single time you press Ctrl+3 (or wherever you put it) it will execute that procedure. If you have a selection, automatically it will bind it with the input parameter.
[image: Select a text, and it will be executed]

The downside, is that you need to create the procedure at any DB you work with.